# Error52 unable to locate Database runtime installation

Tags: c#, database

I created this software that is database related when i install it on my machine and access its database it runs perfectly but when i install it on another machine and i try to access the database it gives this error :

A network-related instance or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The Server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance is correct and that the SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (Provide: SQL Network interfaces: error 52 - Unable to locate the database runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that that the local database runtime feature is enabled

this is the code for the connection i did

```
 var ttg = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="+ttg+"\\Datex Inc\\Time Table Generator\\Database\\timetable.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = con.GetSchema("Tables");
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string tablename = (string)row[2];
            //MessageBox.Show(tablename);
            if (tablename != "schools" && tablename != "records")
            {
                databasenames.Add(tablename);
                box.Items.Add(tablename);
            }
        }

        con.Close();
```

Its really frustrating and i used the visual studio install shield limited edition project to build my installation file which includes the database and primary outputs of my software. Is there anything i did wrong? and how do i properly install my software with database on  another machine with out this error?

Comment: make sure you have the right version of database.  Yup, VS2012's installation project is really a frustrated one.  Hope they revert the VS2010's installation project back.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't looks like issues are with connection string. I had a similar issue with Teamcity and was resolved installing SQL Server Express in the agent. So this looks like the new machine need  SQL Server Express setup installed.

Answer (score 0):

My feel is about the escape sequence.  You already have `@`, then why do you use `\\`.

Try this.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                    AttachDbFilename="+ttg+"\Datex Inc\Time Table Generator
                    \Database\timetable.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: That is not the problem besides if i did that it wont solve the issue thanks.